# How to set process name for Leiningen script so htop shows it as "lein" and not "java... "?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, leiningen

How to set the process name for Leiningen script so htop shows it as "lein" and not "java... "?

Every Leiningen process shows as "java -D..."

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the process name to "lein"
 if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
 # Use setproctitle to set the process name on macOS
  if [ -n "$(command -v setproctitle)" ]; then
    setproctitle "lein"
 fi
fi
```

and:

```
# Set the process name to "lein"
 if [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]; then
   # Use prctl to set the process name on Linux
   if [ -n "$(command -v prctl)" ]; then
     prctl --set-name lein
    fi
 fi
```

I tried these code samples, but the are not installed by default and not working anyway.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `[ a == b ]` is a nonportable extension; the POSIX-standardized form is `[ a = b ]`

Comment: _Related_ to the problem you can use `exec -a argv0 cmd arg1 arg2 ...` _but_ you need to make sure that the lein script does that when it starts the JVM; it doesn't help to do it when you start the lein script yourself -- which means you need to patch or replace the wrapper that the `lein` package itself provides.

Comment: (and looking at lein's wrapper, it's a mess -- sometimes creating a `TRAMPOLINE_FILE` it executes itself, in which case you need to plumb the `-a` usage into the last call in a chain of wrappers calling wrappers; which is to all to say that my personal assessment here is that the juice isn't worth the squeeze, particularly if you want to keep preexisting wrapper features like the ability to honor a `JAVA_CMD` environment variable to select the JVM to use).

Comment: (similarly, if the way your Linux distro's `java` command goes through a wrapper, you need to be sure _that_ wrapper uses `exec -a` so the correct argv0 is passed _when the actual Java executable itself is invoked_, not just when a parent or grandparent is invoked; so see again re: this being probably considerably more trouble than it's worth).